# How to Give A Postgres User SuperUser Previllege Through docker-compose?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, superuser

This is my docker-compose file section for postgres container. These settings are fine, but my django app requires this user to have superuser previlleges through this command inside postgresql.

```
ALTER ROLE project_admin SUPERUSER;
```

How can this be accomodated inside this docker-compose file?

```
 db:
  image: postgres:latest
  container_name: project-db
  environment:
   - POSTGRES_USER='project_admin'
   - POSTGRES_PASS='projectpass'
   - POSTGRES_DB='project'
```

Comment: In Docker Hub, PostgreSQL state clearly for POSTGRES_USER and I quote "This variable will create the specified user with superuser power and a database with the same name". So why do you need to alter the role of 'project_admin' to be a superuser when in the docker compose is already a superuser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to save your command as a script say `./scripts/01_users.sql`:

```
ALTER ROLE project_admin SUPERUSER;
```

Then your docker-compose:

```
...
 db:
  image: postgres:latest
  container_name: project-db
  environment:
   - POSTGRES_USER='project_admin'
   - POSTGRES_PASS='projectpass'
   - POSTGRES_DB='project'
  volumes:
   - ./scripts/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

This will run the script at startup and alter your user's privileges.

Comment: Thanks Mihai, one more thing. Do I need to turn executable bit on this script or would it run anyway?

Comment: It's .sql so it runs anyway